# Broadcom BCM4352 5GHz

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, broadcom

I've been trying to connect to my 5GHz access point with a BCM4352 driven adaptor:

```
Kernel: 4.4.0-64
Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
Drivers: bcmwl-kernel-source 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1
```

I can see the SSID in NetworkManager. When I click connect, it gets stuck at "setting up interface" (I don't know the exact english phrasing, sorry) and after a while automatically connects to my 2.4GHz network (different SSID, works fine).

Exerpt from syslog:
http://pastebin.com/1yLf9MXS

iwlist wlp8s0 s:

```
  Cell 08 - Address: 14:CC:20:EC:6B:5D
            Channel:100
            Frequency:5.5 GHz (Channel 100)
            Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
            Encryption key:on
            ESSID:"<ssid>"
            Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                      36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
            Bit Rates:63.5 Mb/s
            Mode:Master
            Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
            Extra: Last beacon: 84ms ago
            IE: Unknown: 0004326F6735
            IE: Unknown: 01088C129824B048606C
            IE: Unknown: 030164
            IE: Unknown: 3201FF
            IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                Group Cipher : CCMP
                Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
            IE: Unknown: 3B027A00
            IE: Unknown: 2D1AEF091BFFFFFF0000000000000000000100000000000000000000
            IE: Unknown: 3D1664050400000000000000000000000000000000000000
            IE: Unknown: 7F080400000000000040
            IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
```

Both the network and the adapter work! When I boot into Windows 10 or macOS everything's fine. Works with my cell as well.

It also doesn't seem to be related to the regulatory domain as I've tried lots.

I tried with the router set to AC-only, N-only and AC/N, which didn't have any desired effects.

I'm really stuck here and any thoughts on how to make it work (or insight into why it can't) is appreciated!

Comment: Is the 5 gHz set to auto channel or a fixed channel, in this case 100? Please try a lower channel, say channel 40, and tell us if connectivity is improved.

Comment: Neither setting it to 40 nor to auto made the problem disappear.